# UWP MapControl black on transformation with custom tilesource

Tags: c#, dictionary, background, win-universal-app, tile

I'm using a `MapControl` with custom tilesources (OSM via `HttpMapTileDataSource`, replacing the default bing-maps tiles) within an UWP-App.

All in all this works pretty good, but when doing any manipulation (e.g. zooming) to the map the background gets black for a moment (as long as it takes to load the new tilesources (old tiles fade out immediately)) and then switches to the actual new tilesource.

Is there a way to keep the "old" tilesource cached and showing until the new one is done loading to bridge over the black background while loading? (The default bing-maps-layer has exactly this behaviour)

Alternatively is there a way to replace the black background with another background? For example a grid-like background so the user can comprehend the transition of the map in a visual way? (this is pretty much impossible with a black background)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Man how did you did? can you, please, post your code?

Comment: How did I do what? How I solved the problem? Sorry, I don't get your question...

Comment: I finaly found how to make works the changment of tiles (for each plateform). I was stuck for UWP part but now the tiles are customized by mapbow.com :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but this is what you're looking for:

```
YourTileSource.AllowOverstretch = true
```

EDIT:
It appears that indeed, setting `YourTileSource.IsFadingEnabled = false` helps it look better.

Comment: I'm getting a sufficent result with `TileSource.AllowOverstretch = true` **and** `TileSource.IsFadingEnabled = false`, so thank you for your help! 
EDIT: on top of that, I enabled caching for the DataSource. Not perfect, but okay.